# How to build a list of Arrays and convert data like [ a b c d ] to [ "a", "b", "c"]

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to build a list of Arrays and convert data like `[ a b c d ]` to `[ "a", "b", "c"]` using Javascript.

I know this code does the opposite way

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];    
console.log(arr.join(", "));
```

Comment: what is `[ a b c d ]`? PlainText?

Comment: This question is probably a bit more vague than you think. Try look into string splitting with delimiters. For example, you could use spaces as delimiters, like this: `var text="[ a b c d ]"; text.split(" ");`. Note, however, that you'll have the "[" and "]" in the array as well, so you'll need to remove those. (I'm answering this question in a comment, because the linked duplicate answer is definitely not related to this question).

Comment: `const text = '[ a b c d ]'; text.substring(2, text.length - 2).split(' ');` Seems like a weird problem to be solving though...

Comment: Voted to reopen as I don't believe the linked duplicate question is applicable but OP still needs to clarify the state of the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input array is an array of strings, you could write:

```
let arr = ["a b c d", "e", "f g h"];
arr.flatMap(x => x.split(" "));
```

The result is `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]`.